# Defining custom objects and functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, jscript

Can someone explain what is wrong with this JavaScript example, and how to fix it if possible?

```
    // I can define objects / functions like this.
    window['Custom'] = function() { };
    //Works...I now have a 'Custom' function in scope... I can now do this...

    var c = new Custom(); // WORKS!!

    //This does not seem to work!
    window['Custom.prototype.msg'] = function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    };

    // I DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS!
    Custom.prototype.msg = function(msg) { alert(msg); };


    x.msg("Hello");
    //FireFox Error: TypeError: x.msg is not a function...
    // HOW DO I FIX THIS!?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
window.Custom.prototype.msg = function(msg) { ... }
```

The bracket notation takes a string, but the string won't be interpreted as an object graph expression; it's just a string. Thus, `window["Custom.prototype.msg"]` creates a global function called "Custom.prototype.msg".

*edit* — this would also work:

```
window["Custom"]["prototype"]["msg"] = function(msg) { ... }
```

So if you're working with those dotted list expressions for some reason, if you want them to be interpreted as such you'll have to break them up yourself.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want, sorry see my revised example.

Comment: @activwerx well want or don't want whatever, your code won't work as written because it's simply not what JavaScript does.  I'll add another suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: As a curiosity, is there any reason in particular why you wouldn't want to use that notation?

Comment: And thanks for the update, I will accept your answer on that basis!

Comment: The idea is that it should be able to qualify a string to a function. To give an example, I will have a function where I pass in the string representation of a function or object, and its implementation. if an implementation is not already available, it will create a new one, a bit like shim.

Comment: Well OK then you can split the string on the `.` characters and do the object "navigation" with your own code.

Comment: @activwerx - based on your comment "where I pass in the string representation of a function", I recommend doing a search for "eval is evil"...